# Will expending on GPU a good choice if training ML-NLP models is the sole purpose?

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, cpu, training-data

I want to train big data-sets with mainly core ML and NLP models(**Not deep learning**). 
Will GPU make a big difference over here?
I may do some CPU intensive parameter tuning like Grid-search, will GPU make significant improvements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use google [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb) which is offered by google for free and it also used for heavily extensive tasks. Also you can connect your drive for loading data-sets and additional files. Read [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-google-colab-f2fff97f594c) more

Furthermore, you can access the google VM instance for [free](https://cloud.google.com/free/) for 1 year. Which you will get after new registeration. You can read more [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-run-deep-learning-models-on-google-cloud-platform-in-6-steps-4950a57acfa5)

No need to spend on these as for basic uses, these free sources will work for you

Hope this helps....Thanks